Unknown html tag of my angular library component loaded via npm link
I created a simple "single-lib" Angular 16 library, builded and locally published by npm link
ng new angular-libraries --no-create-application
cd angular-libraries
ng generate library single-lib

ng build 

cd dist/single-lib
npm link

In the main application,
I configured the "preserveSymlinks: true" option in angular.json
and I linked the lib:
npm link single-lib

the library was added to the node_module, so far, so good.
In a standalone component of main application,
I add the SingleLibModule to the component imports and it works!
`import {SingleLibModule} from "single-lib"
@Component({
imports: [
SingleLibModule
],
...`
**The problem is that my Intellij IDE does not recognize the library html tag **
"Unknown html tag lib-single-lib".
Am I forgetting some declaration?
IntelliJ html screen
I would expect the html tag to be recognized by the IDE and that I can use it using all the other components of the project and imported components of third-party libraries.
